# How to get reverse of a TRUE/FALSE vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector like :

```
> good.genes
    A     B     C     D     E 
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I want to get it's reverse which would be:

```
    A     B     C     D     E 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Would someone help me do this conversion in R?

Comment: It's not a conversion.  It's called *negation* and it's easily found in the R documentation

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just prepend the `!` operator. As Richard Scriven pointed out, this operation is called *negation*.

```
!good.genes
    A     B     C     D     E 
    TRUE TRUE TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: @RichardScriven, My guess is that the OP did not know the proper name of the operation.

Comment: Quick note--this will also reverse a vector of 1s and 0s. If you had such a vector, `x`, `as.numeric(!x)` will replace all 1s with 0s and vice versa.

Comment: If you are using the forward pipe (%>%) and want to negate a logical vector, remeber that operators are also a function. Use the ` backticks ` around it. Like this:
object %>%
     <some code> %>% ` ! `

Comment: With pipe (%>%) you can also use `isFALSE()` function: for example `TRUE %>% isFALSE()` , this will reverse the logical value

Comment: @GitHunter0 `isFALSE` is not suitable since it expects only one element (vector of length one)